# How to receive Array collection from flex to php

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework, air, zend-amf

I am working on zend Amf php, where the data is send as an array collection from flex (as3) to a PHP service, My question is how to receive the array collection in php side?

I created a class, and included this class on the php service file

```
class Application_Vo_ArrayCollection {

public $source = array();

public function __construct($arr = null) {
    if(isset($arr))
        $this->source = $arr;
    else {
        $this->source = array();
    }
}

public function push($o) {
    array_push($this->source, $o);
}

public function addItem($index, $item) {
    $this->source[$index] = $item;
}
}
```

Now, when the **php service** is invoked from flex.

```
  public function my_php_service( $userdata, Application_Vo_ArrayCollection $questiondata, $requestdata ) {

}
```

an error is thrown, **Unable to parse null body data Unsupported type marker: 17**

I want to make sure is this the correct way of receiving the array collection in php?
**Application_Vo_ArrayCollection $questiondata** in my function definition.

Thanks,

Comment: Please use search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460876/flex-and-zend-amf-how-do-i-get-a-flex-arraycollection-from-flex-into-php

Comment: @llya Z Able to send it as array collection to flex but unable to receive from flex as ArrayCollection type in Zend Amf